# I have updated Safari browser to 15.1 on MacOS Catalina but it has still the old look

Tags: macos, safari

Last night I got an update for the Safari browser on my 13 inches 2012 Mac. I updated it and when opened it has still the old look and nothing feels new. I wonder my Safari doesn't have new features like tabs and all the cool stuff that the new safari comes with. Can someone please tell me why is it like this? Although I am on the latest version of Safari

Comment: What build are you currently running? Safari has had tabs for a LOOOOOOONG time. You wouldn't have been getting them just now unless something else is the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Safari 15 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15-release-notes) I see that the UI was updated for OS 12+. You didn't mention what MacOS version you had, but looking at the [compatibility page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210222) for the differences in OS, a 2012 Mac shouldn't be later than 11.x.

I don't believe you received the UI update due to your Mac not having the hardware requirements (9 years old) to run the latest OS, which is required for the UI update for Safari.

Comment: Oh, It's probably that I am on OS 10.5 that's why. So sad thank you so much for pointing out that